# UIActionSheet Controller crashed on iPad and Works Fine on iPhone

Tags: ipad, crash, ios, uiactionsheet

I've been trying to work a UIActionSheet into my App. The idea is, if you exited the app in a certain state, it would popup on launch and ask you if you'd like to continue or reset. Here's the code:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

continueYesNo = [prefs boolForKey:@"keyContinueMeeting"]; 

if (continueYesNo) {
  NSString *message_continue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Do you want to Continue the Prior Meeting"];
  UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
   initWithTitle:message_continue 
   delegate:self
   cancelButtonTitle:@"Reset" 
   destructiveButtonTitle:@"Continue"
   otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
  [actionSheet release];
  [message_continue release];
}
```

This is in viewDidLoad.  And the actual Code action is:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
 Wasted_TimeAppDelegate  *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

 if (buttonIndex != [actionSheet cancelButtonIndex]) {
  delegate.continueMeeting = YES;
  [prefs setBool:YES forKey:@"keyContinueMeeting"];
         [ [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; 
 } else {
  delegate.continueMeeting = NO;
  [prefs setBool:NO forKey:@"keyContinueMeeting"];
  [ [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];  
 }
}
```

It all seems pretty straight forward, but for some reason it runs on the iPhone with no problem but on the iPad the program crashes at this point.

Comment: Use the "101010" button to format blocks of code so they are readable.

Comment: Can you be more precise about where it crashes? Also, what method and class does the first block of code come from? The second block of code?

Comment: I ran through the debugger and I never get to the UIActionSheet pop up on the screen.

Comment: And I get the following in the debugger: Pending breakpoint 6 - "objc_exception_throw" resolved
Assertion failed: (cls), function getName, file /SourceCache/objc4_Sim/objc4-427.1.1/runtime/objc-runtime-new.m, line 3939.

Comment: NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

 continueYesNo = [prefs boolForKey:@"keyContinueMeeting"]; 
  Actual line that it crashes on is the blank line between the two above lines of code.  Doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: The first code block comes from ViewDidLoad... The Second is the entire block of the UIActionSheet actionsheet code...

Comment: Sorry for some reason the comment is not allowing me to put code blocks in, nor edit correctly with spacing.. if I hit enter it accepts the comment as is.

Comment: Anyone find this one? Or can help me with the answer?  I have completed all my updates for my app, but it will break on the iPad right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this one get's a big fat DOH!  I had incorrectly implemented the iPad XIB, after redeveloping them this works as designed.